# Simple CSS animation to run for all elements

Tags: html, css

Currently, my animation only works for the first element (a progress bar).
I want my animation to run for all of those.

Below is the HTML code to run through several progress bars and JS code to fill the progress bar upon scrolling

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const square = entry.target.querySelector('.progress-bar');

    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      square.classList.add('progress-animation');
      return; // if we added the class, exit the function
    }

    // We're not intersecting, so remove the class!
    square.classList.remove('progress-animation');
  });
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.progress'));
```

```css
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .progress-animation {
    animation: 2s linear 0s normal none infinite running progress-bar-stripes, animate-positive 3s;
    -webkit-animation: 2s linear 0s normal none infinite running progress-bar-stripes, animate-positive 3s;
  }
}
```

```html
<h5>Excel</h5>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-label="Basic example" style="width: 95%;" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  </div>
</div>
<h5>PowerBI</h5>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-label="Basic example" style="width: 85%;" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like that because you use `document.querySelector('.progress')` but to find all elements with that class you should use `document.querySelectorAll('.progress')`. Like that.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.progress').forEach(el => observer.observe(el));
```